# Adapting to the covariance contour plotting example from matplotlib throws singular matrix error

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib

For data evaluation I want to adapt the contour plot of [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_outlier_detection.html). I have a problem understanding what those lines of the example are used for:

```
X1 = 0.3 * np.random.randn(0.5 * n_inliers, 2) - offset 
X2 = 0.3 * np.random.randn(0.5 * n_inliers, 2) + offset
```

Why are there 2 columns? And why 2 X's? I think there are two X only because of the offset.
And I assume the 2 columns each represent a set of data: In a way like a scatter plot, I thought it could mean something like: First columns is for example the MotorRpm, second may be the MotorCurrent of an engine, and came up with this: (`getSeries` is a function that extracts a column out off a dataFrame)

```
ser1 = getSeries("MotorRpm") # type pandas.Series, kind of numpy.array
ser2 = getSeries("MotorCurrent")
blub = []
for i in range(len(ser1)):
    blub.append([ser1.ix[i], ser2.ix[i]])
length = len(blub)
if length%2==1:
    blub.pop(length-1) # make list even

X1 = blub[:length/2]
X2 = blub[length/2:]
```

But this throws a `ValueError: Singular covariance matrix. Please check that the covariance matrix corresponding to the dataset is full rank and that MinCovDet is used with Gaussian-distributed data (or at least data drawn from a unimodal, symmetric distribution.` at the

```
clf.fit(X)
```

line in the example. This also occured as I wanted to check what each of the X's does, changing the randoms to only ones. I know what a singular matrix is - but don't know what the `fit` does internally. If this example is so limited in adapting real life data, what is the real use for it besides of looking nice?

EDIT:
Seems like this warning applies for my case (`MinCovDet(EmpiricalCovariance)`):

```
The Minimum Covariance Determinant covariance estimator is to be applied
on Gaussian-distributed data, but could still be relevant on data
drawn from a unimodal, symmetric distribution. It is not meant to be used
with multi-modal data (the algorithm used to fit a MinCovDet object is
likely to fail in such a case).
One should consider projection pursuit methods to deal with multi-modal
datasets.
```

Answer (score 3):

The explanation to the mystery (why two columns) lies further in the example code:

```
X1 = 0.3 * np.random.randn(0.5 * n_inliers, 2) - offset
X2 = 0.3 * np.random.randn(0.5 * n_inliers, 2) + offset
X = np.r_[X1, X2]
# Add outliers
X = np.r_[X, np.random.uniform(low=-6, high=6, size=(n_outliers, 2))]
```

What this does is that it stacks vertically (along the first axis) three 2-column arrays by using the `numpy.r_`. First part of the array contains points which are offset from the centre by either `(offset,offset)` or `(-offset,-offset)`. The third part of the array contains points which are completely off.

What this means is that actually you have the different axis in different columns. So, you will need to build a Nx2 array from your own data. If your `getSeries` returns a `ndarray` or `pandas.Series`, then this will do:

```
X = np.column_stack((getSeries("MotorRPM"), getSeries("MotorCurrent")))
```

After doing this, check that `X.shape` gives you `(123,2)` (of course the `123` is something else). This should make `clf.fit` happier.

If you have further challenges with your code, please edit your question to show a bit more of what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

EllipticEnvelope is using Minimum Covariance Determinate approach to estimate covariance and detect outliers. But the implementation of MinCovDet (FastMCD) currently has a bug. I checked its code, and it does not handle the case of a singular covariance matrix. This may happen when a subset of your data lies on a hyperplane (or, in a 2-dimensional case, on a line). If that is the case with your data, you could try to use another approach: tell EllipticEnvelope not to use MinCovDet, but the other algorithm they have. I have not checked the other one, not sure if it uses FastMCD as well, but you may try and see if it works - add assume_centered=True option into EllipticEnvelope, as follows:

```
EllipticEnvelope(contamination=.1, assume_centered=True)
```

Here is the description of what it does (from [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html#sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope)):

```
assume_centered : Boolean

If True, the support of robust location and covariance estimates is computed, and a 
covariance estimate is recomputed from it, without centering the data. Useful to work 
with data whose mean is significantly equal to zero but is not exactly zero. If False, 
the robust location and covariance are directly computed with the FastMCD algorithm 
without additional treatment.
```